# Powershell catches wrong exception? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch

Last week I ran into a strange issue.
I modified code that should test if a file is locked and which I once found on the Internet (essentially similar to https://superuser.com/questions/876288/how-do-i-detect-and-skip-locked-files-in-a-powershell-script) to
1) deal with timeout and
2) to handle non existing files (and directories) correctly.

So here is my code:

```
function Test-IsFileLocked {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [System.IO.FileInfo] $File

  , [ref] $MSecsPassed
)

try {
    $Stream = $File.Open([System.IO.FileMode]"Open", [System.IO.FileAccess]"Read", [System.IO.FileShare]"None")
}
# The follwing catch block seems to cause the problem that the 'IO.FileNotFoundException' gets caught after some time (although it is still a simple 'IO.IOException.)
# Outcomment it by removing the '#' in front of '<# ...' to see how all works nicely...
#<#
  catch [System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException] {
    Write-Host "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: '$($_.Exception)'`nType = '$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)'`nType = '$($_.GetType().FullName)'" -ForegroundColor:Yellow
    return $False
}
#>
  catch [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] {
    Write-Host "Caught a 'FileNotFoundException' exception, although the exception still is of type of a simple 'System.IO.IOException'! MSecs passed: $($MSecsPassed.Value)" -ForegroundColor:Red
    Write-Host "FileNotFoundException: '$($_.Exception)'`nType = '$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)'`nType = '$($_.GetType().FullName)'" -ForegroundColor:Yellow
    #if ($_.Exception.GetType().FullName -eq 'System.IO.IOException') {
    #    return $True
    #} else {
        return $False
    #}
} catch [System.IO.IOException] {
    #Write-Host "System.IO.IOException: '$($_.Exception)'`nType = '$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)'`nType = '$($_.GetType().FullName)'"
    if ($_.Exception.GetType().FullName -eq 'System.IO.IOException') {
        return $True
    } else {
        return $False
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "Any Exception: '$($_.Exception)'`nType = '$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)'`nType = '$($_.GetType().FullName)'" -ForegroundColor:Yellow
    if ($_.Exception.GetType().FullName -eq 'System.IO.IOException') {
        return $True
    } else {
        return $False
    }
} finally {
    if ($Stream) {
        $Stream.Dispose()
    }
}
return $False
}

function Wait-UntilFileIsAccessible {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [System.IO.FileInfo] $File

  , [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    [uint32] $CheckIntervalInMSecs

  , [Parameter(Position = 2)]
    [uint32] $Timeout
)

if (!$CheckIntervalInMSecs) {
    $CheckIntervalInMSecs = 500
}

[double] $SecondsPassed = 0.0
[double] $SecondsAdder = [double]$CheckIntervalInMSecs / 1000.0
[uint32] $MSecsPassed = 0

#Write-Verbose "Waiting for '$($File.Fullname)' to get unlocked!"
while (Test-IsFileLocked -File:$File -MSecsPassed:([ref]$MSecsPassed)) {
    Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds:$CheckIntervalInMSecs
    $MSecsPassed += $CheckIntervalInMSecs
    if ($Timeout) {
        $SecondsPassed += $SecondsAdder
        if (([uint32]$SecondsPassed) -ge $Timeout) {
            return $False
        }
    }
}
#Write-Vebose "'$($File.Fullname)' now isn't locked anymore"
return $True
}
```

If I call this code with

```
Wait-UntilFileIsAccessible -File:'C:\LockedByMSWord.txt' -Timeout:30
```

where 'C:\LockedByMSWord.txt' is an existing file actually locked (e.g. opened with MS Word) then after some time (16500 ms in most cases for me) the **'IO.FileNotFoundException'** gets caught although the exception thrown seems to be of type **'IO.IOException'**.
If I then repeat the call to 'Wait-UntilFileIsAccessible' then usually Powershell immediately catches this 'wrong' exception.
It drove me nuts and I tried different things until I removed the code block that catches the 'IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' (for testing purposes initially) just to find out that then everything works as expected.

Am I doing something wrong here (I mean with the code that catches this 'IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' exception), do I misunderstand something or could this be a Powershell bug?

This is with Powershell 4 and ErrorActionPreference set to 'Continue'.
Also some code obviously is just in there for testing purposes (I wouldn't need ref parameter MSecsPassed in Test-IsFileLocked and output to host normally)

P.S.: I know how to workaround it, but I would like feedback to my question if I am doing something wrong in my code or if this possibly could be a bug in Powershell.

Thanks,
Patrik

Comment: Not sure I understand the "although the exception thrown seems to be of type 'IO.IOException'" part. `IO.FileNotFoundException` *is* an `IO.IOException`, since the former inherits from the latter

Comment: Yes, I know that IO.FileNotFoundException _is_ and IO.IOException.  
But if - as I do it in the presented code - call a GetType on the caught exception, then it should be - if I do not misunderstand anything completely - of type 'IO.FileNotFoundException' in the catch handler for 'IO.FileNotFoundException'.

Comment: And in the presented test scenario the code execution path really never should come into this handler, since the file exists (and is locked by MS word).
The example does everything correctly (the 'normal' 'IO.IOException' gets caught) if I outcomment the catch 'IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' part.
Did you already try to reproduce?
Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Anyone interested to help me with my problem?

Comment: Sure, but I'm as confounded as you are (yes, I could reproduce this). If you swap around the Directory and File IOException catch blocks, behavior persists but still with the second catch block being executed. As if PowerShell skips the first catch blocks because of type mismatch and then just "takes the nearest exit" without checking the type in the second block. I would report this as a bug on Microsoft Connect

Comment: Thanks Mathias!   
It was my intention to report this to Microsoft Connect, but I first wanted to make sure that someone could reproduce this strange behavior.  
So now since you could reproduce, I will report this to Microsoft Connect.

Comment: For anyone interested:  
The according [Microsoft Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1953815/powershell-4-and-5-catches-wrong-exception-after-some-time)

Comment: @PatrikE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767970/powershell-executes-the-wrong-exception-handler/51953447#51953447 is similar and seems to have been fixed in PS Core. Can you check if yours is fixed as well? If so, you may want to post on the UserVoice issue to request a backport of the fix.

Comment: Independently of that, you may also want to link this SO question / code sample in the UserVoice directly, since Connect has been retired.

Comment: @Arnavion Yes my issue too seems to be fixed in Powershell Core.
Tried it with 6.0.4.
I added a comment to my UserVoice feedback containing all relevant links here on SO.
https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/12963303-bug-powershell-4-and-5-catches-wrong-exception-a

But I doubt that anyone there cares...
This UserVoice thing is such a pain for bug reporting... (Voting system ???)